# How to show activity from activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

i need some help about activity stack.

In my app i have 6 screens user navigate from

```
  1-->2-->3-->4-->
```

when i go to 4 screen i have cancel button

when user click on that button it should go to second screen and

when user clicks back button on keypad it should go to **1 screen which was already in activity stack** how to do this.

Please give me a example.

Comment: I've edited ma answer. FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP will take you to first screen which was already in activity stack.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

When user clicks button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityD.this, ActivityB.class);
Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

When user presses back:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityD.this, ActivityA.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

This code will take the user to first activity.The activity won't be recreated because of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.  When activity is already on back stack the onNewIntent() will be invoked in which you can use data from intent for example.

If you want such behaviors as default for yours activities put these flags to android manifest into activity declarations.

Comment: out of curiosity, is this available from 1.5? i was not aware of that flag so thanks :)

Comment: This flag is available since API 1. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `onBackPressed()` and intent mechanism to launch or reshow necessary activity.

Comment: thank you Madimir, but onBackPressed() is not available in android - 1.5.

Comment: but i want to show 1 screen which was already in activity stack.

Answer (score 0):

//For Back btn on screen 4

```
Onclick(View v)
{
if(v==Backbtn)
{
finish();
startActivity(new intent(this,SecondActivity.class));
}
}
```

// for back key press to return to 1 screen

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            startActivity(new intent(this,FirstActivity.class));
                     return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Your code will start SecondActivity on Third, and First on Fourth activity. Pressing back button will show respectively Third and Fourth activity on top.